# Installing IIS on Windows XP SP3 with no media (CD/DVD)

Tags: iis, windows-xp-sp3

I got my system rebuilt and guy forgot to install IIS.
Its Windows XP SP3.  I dont have CD / DVD of Windows XP SP3 install IIS.
Is this can downloaded? if yes where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://apdubey.blogspot.com/2009/03/install-iis-in-windows-xp-without.html this will be a help